# What should I write as tag message when finishing a release?

Tags: git, git-flow

I started a release using `git flow release start 1.0.0`

When I finish it `git flow release finish '1.0.0'`, it asks for a tag message. And I get a fatal error if I leave it empty.

What should I write into the message tag?

A colleague tells me to type the version number, is it a good practice?

Comment: Depends on your organization's conventions. `git flow release finish '1.0.0' -m '1.0.0'` is fairly widely practiced, but in isolation not a very good idea; you should then have useful documentation about the release somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no perfect answer for this type of questions.

As for the commit message, the real things that you should want to put into is:

**what "future you" will expect to have if one day you need some information about this release**.

Starting from there, you could imagine some things:

- as this information will be used in an annotated tag, you could indeed write the version number (one reason is to find it again easily in case of accident if you deleted the tag and have to find it again in the reflog)
- a release note (list of feature, known bugs, ....)
- the list of commits or PR contained in this release,
- other information that your project or company link to a release (download link, id or url of the release in other products, ....)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Tag message is essentially similar to a commit message, but for annotated tags. It depends on what conventions you adopted. Most of the times annotated tags are related to releases, so you might use it to publish your release notes/or a release documentation link.